# Connect NetBeans to SQLite

Tags: database, netbeans, sqlite, netbeans-8

How can I connect `NetBeans IDE 8.2` to `SQLite (3.16.1)` ?

I have tried it with `Java` but I Need to Code in `C`. 
I thought making the Connection in `Java` but then coding 
with `C` in a different Project could help, but that did not work.

Comment: Just write code that calls the appropriate SQLite functions. What exactly is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to code in JAVA:

```
import java.sql.*;

public class SQLiteJDBC
{
  public static void main( String args[] )
  {
    Connection c = null;
    try {
      Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
      c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:test.db");
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
      System.err.println( e.getClass().getName() + ": " + e.getMessage() );
      System.exit(0);
    }
    System.out.println("Opened database successfully");
  }
}
```

in
https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm